# Testing a simple GET request from NodeJS

Tags: node.js, httprequest

For testing purpose,I want to call a method (that does GET request) as soon as the server is created. I have the below code.

```
var rp = require('request-promise');
var http = require('http');

var URLSplunk = MY_URL

var headersSplunk = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer MY_AUTH',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'X-Requested-By': 'BABEL_FISH',
    'client': 'slack'
};

function testSplunk(){
  var optionsSplunk = {
      url: URLSplunk,
      headers: headersSplunk,
      json: true
  };

  rp(optionsSplunk)
      .then(function (resultReply) {
        console.log("Splunk GET success")
        console.log(resultReply)
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(`Error: \n${error}`);
      });

}

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    testSplunk()
}).listen(3000);

console.log('Server started');
```

I was expecting to see the GET result or error but I only see '`Server started`' message.

What am I missing?

Comment: Try putting testSplunk(); after the create server function.

Comment: The way you have the code now, your `testSplunk()` function will get called only when your http server gets a request.  It's inside the http server requestListener callback.  So, you have to send the http server a request to trigger that callback so the `testSplunk()` function gets called.  It's unclear whether that's how you want it to work or not, but that's what your current code will do.

Comment: @Philip556677 thanks it worked. If you put it as an answer I will mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My comment echo'd in greater detail by @jfiend00.

> The way you have the code now, your testSplunk() function will get called only when your http server gets a request. It's inside the http server requestListener callback. So, you have to send the http server a request to trigger that callback so the testSplunk() function gets called.

The testSplunt() function is never being called by the program until a request is made to the server.

Putting it after the requestListener callback will allow for it to be executed in the manner that you want it to be.

E.g.

```
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    //This function is called when the server gets a request
    //Process request.......
}).listen(3000);

testSplunk();

console.log('Server started');
```